# Using powershell for newbie

Tags: powershell

im trying to figure out task b)using PowerShell. i used get-psdrive for task a) but im lost with task b)
any help would be great im new to PowerShell

a) Display a list of disk volumes. 
b) Display a list that shows the members of the objects produced by the previous command.

Comment: Did you mean this? `get-psdrive | get-member`

Comment: im not sure what i put up is all i got to go on,and looking at task one i think Get-Volume would be a better option